# Trying to set sonar log level to INFO

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to set sonar log level to INFO.

I tried to use `sonar-project.properties` and set the `sonar.log.level = INFO` but its not working.

Any help on this please?

```
sonar.log.level = INFO
```

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/system-info/) INFO is the default. Read this page and explain more clearly what is not working.

Comment: yes @JeroenHeier INFO is default but here DEBUG is enabled and i want to force sonar to use INFO for my application during scan

Comment: The settings can be set on multiple places. Read [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-parameters).

Comment: sonar-scanner -Dsonar.verbose=true

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and it turned out that I was passing `-X` flag to the `sonar-scanner` command. It seems that this flag overrides the `sonar.log.level` setting and always sets it to `DEBUG`.
Here is the documentation of the `sonar-scanner` command: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/

Answer (score 0):

Removal of -X from sonar-scanner command worked for me.
DEBUG mode turned in INFO.

INFO: 184/184 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Java Main Files AST scan (done) | time=35544ms
INFO: Java Test Files AST scan
INFO: 0 source files to be analyzed
INFO: Java Test Files AST scan (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Java Generated Files AST scan
INFO: 0 source files to be analyzed
INFO: Java Generated Files AST scan (done) | time=4ms